# what are the options for obtaining k pair-wise independent hash functions that are fast

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, hash, bloom-filter

I ran into the needs of k pair-wise independent hash functions, each takes as input an integer, and produces a hash value in the range of 0-N. Need this for count-min sketch, which is similar to Bloom filter.

Formally, I need h_1,h_2, ..., h_k hash functions, pair-wise independent.

(h_i(n) mod N ) will give the hash value of n in the range of 0-N. The hashing needs to be time-efficient as I am working with a large set of data. At the same time, they should be as pair-wise independent as possible.

What I have tried so far:

1) xxhash: It is efficient, but it is not good in terms of pair-wise independent, meaning there are hash collisions between hash functions (meaning h1(n1)=h1(n2) then some h_k(n1) also = h_k(n2)) and the result i got was bad due to this.

2) Similarly, the famous integer hashing method ((a*n+b) mod p) mod N also has the same problem as xxhash. I believe this is called Universal hashing

3) The other one introduced in count-min-sketch produces quite good results, but takes too much time for a large input.

4) Also tried Murmur3, sha1 with similar problems in collisions.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated. C/C++ preferred, but Java would also be fine, or simply algorithm.
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to make a Bloom filter...

Comment: Almost exactly. It's count-min sketch, an improved algorithm for bloom filter.

Comment: @simo what is your DataSet(is it integers,String etc)

Comment: Are you sure about integer hashing? section 2.3 claim 5 of http://people.csail.mit.edu/ronitt/COURSE/S12/handouts/lec5.pdf is a proof based on modular arithmetic that hash functions of this sort are pair-wise independent - or possibly you mean something else by this term?

Comment: If you need multiple functions taken together to be independent try using different primes - by the Chinese Remainder Theorem the concatenated results should form one big pairwise independent hash functions.

Comment: If you start off with a single hash function g(x) and define H_i(x) = g(i|x) where i is concatenation or similar then collision between H_i() and H_j() looks like collision between g(i|x) and g(j|x) so a single good hash function may produce multiple good H_i() - but you should have seen this with ax+b mod p because using different (a,b) pairs is pretty close to pre-processing x to concatentate it with i.

Comment: @VikramBhat The dataset contains IDs of users. IDs are integers. The number of users can be millions. So need a good and fast hash to hash IDs.

Comment: @mcdowella I meant exactly that. That was the first one I tried. Normally, it makes good hash, but when you have a large dataset, it makes lots of collisions.

Comment: What do you call h_k(n1) ? (regarding xxhash, and compared to h1(n1)) ? do you mean, same input, but using different seed ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your problem with method 2 is that you tossed a_i and b_i that were correlated.
Work in large field (somewhere near 2^64) and for starters make sure all a_i and b_i are different (i.e., you get 2*k different numbers). If they are uniformly distributed inside the field this also wouldn't hurt :)

You might encountered the same problem in method 4 with SHA. Most cryptographic hash functions (including even the broken and older ones) are much more than enough for data structures needs, be it k-wise independence for any reasonable k, or almost any other property.
I would recheck - how you used it?